# No class Registered cloud endpoints

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I am using google cloud endpoints with objectify to store data for an app. If i make requests to the api ive created i am getting:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
11-23 09:39:03.711  27884-28100/com.nicky W/System.err﹕ {
11-23 09:39:03.711  27884-28100/com.nicky W/System.err﹕ "code": 400,
11-23 09:39:03.711  27884-28100/com.nicky W/System.err﹕ "errors": [
11-23 09:39:03.711  27884-28100/com.nicky W/System.err﹕ {
11-23 09:39:03.711  27884-28100/com.nicky W/System.err﹕ "domain": "global",
11-23 09:39:03.711  27884-28100/com.nicky W/System.err﹕ "message": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class 'com.nicky.mybackend.Post' was registered",
11-23 09:39:03.711  27884-28100/com.nicky W/System.err﹕ "reason": "badRequest"
11-23 09:39:03.711  27884-28100/com.nicky W/System.err﹕ }
11-23 09:39:03.711  27884-28100/com.nicky W/System.err﹕ ],
11-23 09:39:03.711  27884-28100/com.nicky W/System.err﹕ "message": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class 'com.nicky.mybackend.Post' was registered"
11-23 09:39:03.711  27884-28100/com.nicky W/System.err﹕ }
```

I know i have the Post.class registered in the ObjectifyService class, and i am able to create Post objects in the android client. Here is the objectifyService class:

```
public class OfyService {

    static {
        ObjectifyService.register(RegistrationRecord.class);
        ObjectifyService.register(Post.class);
    }

    public static Objectify ofy() {
        return ObjectifyService.ofy();
    }

    public static ObjectifyFactory factory() {
        return ObjectifyService.factory();
    }
}
```

Here is the endpoint method from which i am calling in the android client:

```
@ApiMethod(
            name = "insert",
            path = "post",
            httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.POST)
    public Post insert(Post post) {
        ofy().save().entity(post).now();
        logger.info("Created Post with ID: " + post.getId());

        return ofy().load().entity(post).now();
    }
```

I am making calls the the backend from asynctask like so:

```
        Post result;
        PostEndpoint service = AppConstants.getApiHandle(credential);
        Post temp = new Post();
        c.setTime(new Date());
        temp.setPostTime(c.getTimeInMillis());

        result = service.insert(temp).execute();
```

I have not secured the server side of things but i am making requests using GoogleAccountCredential that has the username from the android account on the phone. I am not aware of any other place i need to register my endpoint model classes. Any help is appreciated thanks

Comment: Any chance you have the wrong static import for ofy()? It should be OfyService.ofy() and not ObjectifyService.ofy().

Comment: thank you, that fixed the problem....i had this as an import: import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService instead of my own ofyservice class

Comment: It's an easy enough mistake to make that it might be worth revising the "best practices" to recommend doing registration some other way (say, a servlet contest listener). On the other hand, this works in test cases too.

Comment: @stickfigure Thank you so much. My Android Studio for randomly changed my static import and I was so confused as to why despite me having entities in my datastore it was telling me I did not have the entity registered! I think the Intellij IDE auto imports are too aggressive or something!

Answer (score 2):

I don't want to assign, confer the correct answer but this comment had the right answer:

> Blockquote Any chance you have the wrong static import for ofy()? It should be OfyService.ofy() and not ObjectifyService.ofy()

So, when you create the endpoints Android Studio auto import the library

```
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;
```

when you need to import your Ofy class.

So, in my case I've imported it instead of the other and even I put the name of my Ofy class like:

```
 OfyService.ofy().save().entity
```

or

```
 OfyService.ofy().delete().entity
```